# Kibana server is not ready yet and logstash 401 error in docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, kibana, elk

I'm new to the `ELK stack`
I watched a youtube tutorial and setup the ELK in my local using docker, here the [youtube video link](https://youtu.be/VpAH2IoMzKw)

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.6'
services:
 Elasticsearch:
   image: elasticsearch:8.6.2
   container_name: elasticsearch
   restart: always
   volumes:
   - elastic_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
   environment:
     ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
     discovery.type: single-node   
   ports:
   - '9200:9200'
   - '9300:9300'
   networks:
     - elk


 Logstash:
   image: logstash:8.6.2
   container_name: logstash
   restart: always
   volumes:
   - ./logstash/:/logstash_dir
   command: logstash -f /logstash_dir/logstash.conf
   depends_on:
     - Elasticsearch
   ports:
   - '9600:9600'
   environment:
     LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"   
   networks:
     - elk


 Kibana:
   image: kibana:8.6.2
   container_name: kibana
   restart: always      
   ports:
   - '5601:5601'
   environment:
     - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200 
   depends_on:
     - Elasticsearch 
   networks:
     - elk
volumes:
 elastic_data: {}


networks:
 elk:
```

I had created one more file in my local machine `logstash/logstash.conf`

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/root/temp/anteater.log"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    }
}
```

after that i ran this command in terminal

> docker compose up

I got this **error** in terminal

```
logstash       | [2023-03-08T06:46:20,779][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", 
:exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
```

`elasticsearch` host `http://localhost:9200/` in that host im getting this output (in chrome)

```
{
  "name" : "4e1e8f4b954e",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "TqKXbDUpRQyJNvD8posibg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.6.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "2d58d0f136141f03239816a4e360a8d17b6d8f29",
    "build_date" : "2023-02-13T09:35:20.314882762Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.4.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

`logstash` host `http://localhost:9600/` im getting this (in chrome)

```
{"host":"14a409d312cf","version":"8.6.2","http_address":"0.0.0.0:9600","id":"9fbe55d7-33d8-4218-8d86-0c52dec234a3","name":"14a409d312cf","ephemeral_id":"e0bb3a33-fcdc-4248-9a7e-d8837f6a5cd1","status":"green","snapshot":false,"pipeline":
{"workers":6,"batch_size":125,"batch_delay":50},"build_date":"2023-02-12T05:42:46+00:00","build_sha":"4f0229a28712eb16c78e6c8eaff04560828a6ae2","build_snapshot":false}
```

`kibana`  host `http://localhost:5601/` im getting this in chrome

```
Kibana server is not ready yet.
```

After that, I tried to access this `http://elasticsearch:9200`  host in chrome as mentioned in the `docker-compose.yml` file, I'm getting this error

```
This site can’t be reached
Check if there is a typo in elasticsearch.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

after inspecting the `logstash`  container
in `pipeline/logstash.conf`

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

in `config/logstash.yml`

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]
```

I had tried so many solutions but still im getting this error, please help me solve this

Comment: Are you sure elasticsearch is not using `https` ?

Comment: Look for offical docker compose it should help

Comment: @Paulo the `elasticsearch` is not using https, it's running in my localhost. and moreover if I try to run the `http://elasticsearch:9200` in chrom im getting like `Site can't be reached`, but the container running it's open in `localhost:9200`

Comment: What happen if you try `https://localhost:9200` ?

Comment: `https` ? okay if I try `https://localhost:9200`  getting this error
`This site can’t provide a secure connection`

but if i use `http://localhost:9200`  getting this `200` response
```
{
  "name" : "0905c3bc1528",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "TqKXbDUpRQyJNvD8posibg",
  "version" : {
   ....
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.4.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Could you rename your services from `Elasticsearch` to `elasticsearch` / `Logstash` to `logstash` / `Kibana` to `kibana` in your docker compose ?
Although dns should be case insensitive ... I think docker dns implementation is ... not sure please test ^^

Comment: `getting  error`
logstash       | [2023-03-10T06:20:31,971][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
logstash       | org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
logstash       |        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:790) ~[jruby.jar:?]
logstash       |        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:753) ~[jruby.jar:?]
logstash       |        at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:91) ~[?:?]
logstash exited with code 1

Comment: @Paulo but I used the the `container_name` key word right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252433/discussion-between-l-o-c-o-and-paulo).

Answer (score 0):

after updating the `logstash.conf` file like this

```
input {
   file {
       path => "/root/temp/anteater.log"
   }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
       user => "elastic"
       password => "changeme"
   }
}
```

replace the `changeme` to the correct `password`

Add one more file in the `logstash` folder in my `local machine` or `host machine` with name of `logstash.yml`.

**logstash.yml**

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: elastic
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme
```

then changing the `docker-compose.yml` file. to mount this file in `logstash` container

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 Logstash:
   image: logstash:${TAG}
   container_name: logstash
   restart: always
   volumes:
   - ./logstash/:/logstash_dir
   - ./logstash/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
   command: logstash -f /logstash_dir/logstash.conf
   depends_on:
     - Elasticsearch
   ports:
   - '9600:9600'
   environment:
     LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m" 
   networks:
     - elk
```

I added this line in `Logstash` service

`- ./logstash/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml`

after that have to create one more file with the name of `kibana.yml` in the host machine in side the `kibana` directory

**kibana / kibana.yml**

```
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.shutdownTimeout: "5s"
elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]
monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true


elasticsearch.username: kibana_system
elasticsearch.password: <KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD>
```

after that mount this local file with `Kibana service`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
 Kibana:
   image: kibana:${TAG}
   container_name: kibana
   restart: always      
   ports:
   - '5601:5601'
   volumes:
   - ./kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
   environment:
     - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200 
   depends_on:
     - Elasticsearch
   healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:5601/"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5 
   networks:
     - elk
```

I added this extra two line

```
   volumes:
   - ./kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
```

then run all the containers

> docker compose up

Everything Done :-) happy coding